# Order of Execution asked in a Interview

Tags: order-of-execution

What should we answer when this question is asked in interview.
There are lot in the list. cant really remember all of them by order.

Comment: If you try to remember you won't succeed. If you try to understand the order you will remember all of them by order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *should* generally know that the basic process is validations, before triggers, after triggers, configurable rules (assignment, auto-response), workflows and processes, roll-ups, commit, and emails. Generally speaking, the *exact* order doesn't usually matter, since the save order is generally designed to follow the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

You should also know that there's documentation if something you build doesn't work the way you expect, and you suspect that the order of operations are affecting you-- this is incredibly rare, to the point where I'd *expect* an average developer to have to refer to the manual if they ran into such a situation.

I've never interviewed for a place that expected me to list every step, in the correct order, including all the minutiae, and ended up working there. We have a manual for a reason. And it's a large manual, thousands and thousands of pages of text. We're only human, and we're not expected to remember everything. But we do need to know the basics, and be able to reason out why something's not working right.

Comment: reminds me of a SFDC Cert question I once faced: "Where would an admin configure multi-language support for SFDC feature XXX?" with four possible answers. Given that an admin might have to do this anywhere between 0 and a handful of times in their lifetime; it was unfortunate that one of the answers wasn't "consult the doc".